# Spring boot integration test with environment variables

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-test, wiremock

I'm working on a multi-module maven project using Java 8, Spring Boot 2.4.0. I want to test one of a module that is calling a 3rd party service. I'm using wiremock to mock that 3rd party service call and have created a spring boot integration test class. My class is in the same package where my XYZService class is. My test is in src/test/... and looks like this.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringApplicationClassWithMainMethod.class)
public class XYZServiceIntegrationTest {

@Rule
public WireMockRule externalService = new WireMockRule();

@Test
public void test1() {...}

@Test
public void test2() {...}
}
```

When I run the maven build in my eclipse (clean + install). My build is not detecting the tests present at the maven-module where the Integration test is located. The other unit tests in the same module are also not being detected (Note: before adding the integration test class, the unit tests were working). Maven says Tests ran: 0. The integration test is working fine when I Right click on the file and run as JUnit test(Junit 4). Also, I have some environment variables that need to be set for running the SpringApplicationClassWithMainMethod.class that I'm setting within the configurations of that Integration test class in order to successfully load the Application context(I tried to load the environment variables through code and nothing from other stack-overflow posts worked). One more thing to inform my maven only uses Maven surefire plugin for running tests. I dont know if we need to have Maven fail safe plugin for my purpose(Is my test considered a Integration Test when I added the 2 annotations on top of the test class?). Can someone please help me with any suggestions on how to build the parent project.

Comment: Which Spring Boot Version do you use?

Comment: I'm using Spring boot 2.4.0

Comment: Then you should use JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5) instead of JUnit 4 otherwise you need to add the junit-vintage-engine to run your JUnit 4 tests..

Comment: I'm using JUnit4 as power Mockito only supports JUnit4 as of now. Also, My JUnit4 tests were running properly before when I used to run maven clean & maven install. Only after I added the above XYZServiceIntegrationTest class none of the tests are being run during Maven build(clean + install).

Comment: can you add the `<build>` part of your `pom.xml`?

Comment: The above example uses `@RunWith(..` which is JUnit 4... the question is why you need power mockito .. and not using Mockito instead ... furthermore I would suggest to name your integration test like `*IT.java` which is the default naming schema for maven-failsafe-plugin... furthermore if you need to run tests you don't need to run `install` you can do `verify` instead....

Comment: @rieckpil I am using <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId><version>3.0.0-M5</version>, <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>, <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId><version>2.5.3</version>.

I'm not using power mockito in the above integration test. I'm only using Mockito to mock the url field so that I can call wiremock instead of actual server. I've tried following the *IT.java convention as well but it didnt work for some reason. Also, I dont have maven-failsafe-plugin in my build. I tried to use a snippet for maven-fail-safe from internet but it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Adding the maven-failsafe-plugin into my child pom worked. In the parent pom I added the execution goals for maven-failsafe-plugin in the  and in the child pom I inherited that plugin.